Install mold linker on ubuntu 20.04
I wanted to use mold linker to build my c++ and rust project.
i tried to install it via apt
$ sudo apt install mold
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mold

But seems like mold is not included as package for ubuntu 20.04.
How should I install mold for ubuntu 20.04 . Is it possible to install it via ppa?

Why not upgrade to 24.04? Usually, new software are not backported to older versions of ubuntu, and also, 20.04 would reach end of support in 7 months

Thank you for the reply. i wanted to continue on 20.04 for sometime .but i will consider upgrading to 24.04
